# NodeJS module to calculate linear motion

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, modules, physics

I am on the process of changing jobs, so I would like to get an idea of what I do wrong in order to improve.

For this, I have created a small node module. It's very simple; it calculates linear motion (distance, velocity, time). I am interested in knowing what I do wrong, whether it's some crucial mistake or something secondary as the way I format my comments.

```
/**
*   Checks whether two values are valid to be operated with
*   @param {Float} operandA
*   @param {Float} operandB
*   @return {Boolean}
*/
const areValuesValid = (operandA, operandB) => {
    if(isNaN(operandA) || isNaN(operandB)) return false;

    if(operandA === null || operandB === null) return false;

    return true;
}

/**
*   Rounds a value to a max of two decimals
*   @param {Float} val
*   @return {Float}
*/
const round = (val) => {
    return Math.round(val * 100) / 100;
}

/**
*   Calculates the time in relation to the velocity and the distance
*   @param {Float} velocity
*   @param {Float} distance
*   @return {Float}
*/
const calculateTime = (velocity, distance) => {
    if(areValuesValid(velocity, distance) === false)
        return 0;

    if(parseFloat(velocity) === 0)
        return 0;

    return round(distance / velocity);
}

/**
*   Calculates the velocity in relation to the time and the distance
*   @param {Float} time
*   @param {Float} distance
*   @return {Float}
*/
const calculateVelocity = (time, distance) => {
    if(areValuesValid(time, distance) === false)
        return 0;

    if(parseFloat(time) === 0)
        return 0;

    return round(distance / time);
}

/**
*   Calculates the distance in relation to the velocity and the time
*   @param {Float} velocity
*   @param {Float} time
*   @return {Float}
*/
const calculateDistance = (velocity, time) => {
    if(areValuesValid(velocity, time) === false)
        return 0;

    return round(velocity * time);
}

module.exports = { areValuesValid, calculateTime, calculateVelocity, calculateDistance }
```

If anybody is willing to go the extra mile, I have created a repository with this code, which also includes some tests. [Github](https://github.com/ybrodsky/node-linear-motion/tree/f18c8e39106e19fcde92f83c512667c01fb2245a). I would like to know if I go about the tests the right way, if the module structure makes sense and whatever else is criticizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice documentation. This code is clear and easy to read. Here are some basic nits:

1. You should probably follow standard [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html) conventions. Don't do this:

   ```
   /**
   *
   */
   ```

   Do this instead:

   ```
   /**
    *
    */
   ```

   If you're nitpicky about the `@param`, `Float` technically doesn't exist since all JavaScript numbers are floats. Use `Number` instead.
2. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762768/javascript-math-round-to-two-decimal-places) about rounding to 2 decimal places. Using it is completely up to you, there's nothing wrong with the way you're doing it. (This suggestion is slower, but looks cool I guess)

   ```
   const round = val => {
       return +val.toFixed(2);
   };
   ```
3. You know the constraints of your `areValuesValid()` function, there's no need to `=== false`.

   ```
   const calculateTime = (velocity, distance) => {
       if (areValuesValid(velocity, distance) && parseFloat(velocity) !== 0) {
           return round(distance / velocity);
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Also, why the need to do `parseFloat(velocity)`? If you know all your arguments will be numbers, this is unnecessary. If you don't know the data type of your arguments, you should probably enforce that they are numbers using `typeof`.

Happy coding!

Comment: Roger on the comments. I did `=== false` to avoid doing `!areValuesValid()` I was told that evaluating to false requires (at the processor level) the inversion of the truth tables, so it takes a little (insignificant nowadays) more time. As for the `parseFloat`, I was covering my ass in case somebody sends strings as params, which will work throughout the function except in that evaluation. I guess I could also remove the `parseFloat` and evaluate with `!=` instead of `!==`. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: It depends on what you want this to be used for. If this is a user facing module/api that other people will be calling, then strong argument type checks are good. If this is going to be used internally in a project of your own, you can establish reasonable expectations for the parameters and their types. Also, I'd appreciate if you accepted this answer if it helped :)